# How to create folder in the internal storage instead of /storage/emulated/0 in Android?

Tags: java, android

[image]I am trying to create an app that would create a folder inside the internal storage of the Android device in the same name as the app. (like Whatsapp) I have been trying to implement this using "mkdir". Here is the sample code I am trying:

```
File appFolder;
    String path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.getRootDirectory().getParent())
            .getAbsolutePath() +"/student";

    appFolder = new File(path);

    if(!appFolder.exists()){
        boolean b = appFolder.mkdir();
    }
```

The problem is that the folder is being created in "/storage/emulated/0" directory. But I want it to be created in the root of Internal storage like Whatsapp.(like the pic where there is a folder for "Collage maker" app) How can I achieve that? Thanks in advance for your kind support in this regard.

---

Comment: Well what is full path of whatsapp directory? Pretty unclear what you consider to be root of internal storage.

Comment: When you go to the internal storage, you would see folders like "Whatsapp", "Imo" etc. I am targeting to do something like that.

Comment: You should tell full path as instuctions as go to internal storage are not for programmers and i do not know what you mean by that.

Comment: Use a good file manager that does not tell nonsense like internal storage but shows full path.

Comment: I have changed the file manager. After digging a lot, I have found that Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory can do the trick. But it is deprecated in API level 29.

Comment: And the normal DCIM folder full path is /storage/emulated/0/DCIM. So what is it that you want?

Comment: bro have you got the method to do this?

Answer (score 0):

yes it can be created.
LOC_DIR = student

```
val dir= File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null), LOC_DIR) // android 9 and above
 // use context.getFilesDir() if you want in internal storage
     //dir = File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), LOC_DIR) below android 9
     // Environment.getRootDirectory() if you want in internal storage
        if(!dir.exists()) {

            file.mkdir()
            Log.d(TAG, "Dir created" + dir.path)
        }
```

Comment: Check the return value of file.mkdir() before you shout that it is created.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for internal folder:

```
val rootPath = context.filesDir.absolutePath
```

Comment: This is being stored in "/data/user/0/com.example.student/files" folder. My problem is not solved.